# Business-Objects vs Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports, business-objects

Would someone please explain the difference? Are these the same product, and if not what are they each used for?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Crystal Reports is a design tool--you use it to create and maintain reports.  It is similar to Desktop Intelligence and Microsoft Access is this regard.  It also has an SDK (COM, .Net, Java)
 for programmatical access.

BusinessObjects Enterprise is a report-deployment platform:

- supports a variety of report types (e.g. Crystal Reports, WebI, OLAPi/Voyager)
- uses a desktop metaphor, called InfoView (nee ePortfolio), to allow people to access reports
- has an Administrative console, called the Central Management Console (nee Crystal Management Console), to manage various aspects of these reports, including DB authentication
- comprise of a number of Windows/Unix/Linus services (e.g. Job Server, Central Management Server, File Repository Server)
- enforces access privileges (via NT, AD, LDAP, or Enterprise authenitcation)
- runs reports on a schedule
- distributes reports (via email, ftp, and other mechanisms)
- has an SDK (COM, .Net, Java) to manage these aspects of the reports.

Answer (score 3):

[Business Objects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_Objects_%28company%29) is an enterprise which specializes in Business Intelligence and delivers tools which mainly help in analyzing, reporting enterprise data.

[Crystal Reports](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crystal_Reports) primarily covers design and creation of different types of reports from various data sources. It was acquired by Business Objects.

Comment: And in turn, Business Objects was acquired by SAP

Answer (score 1):

Besides the answer you got above, Crystal Reports Server is a limited version of the Business Objects Enterprise product.